# POSIX statvfs required behaviour

Tags: c, filesystems, posix, standards

POSIX [statvfs()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/statvfs.html) description says:

> The following flags can be returned in the f_flag member:
>
> - ST_RDONLY - Read-only file system.
> - ST_NOSUID - Setuid/setgid bits ignored by exec.
>
> It is unspecified whether all members of the statvfs structure have meaningful values on all file systems.

Also [sys/statvfs.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_statvfs.h.html) description:

> The `<sys/statvfs.h>` header shall define the following symbolic constants for the f_flag member:
>
> - ST_RDONLY - Read-only file system.
> - ST_NOSUID - Does not support the semantics of the ST_ISUID and ST_ISGID file mode bits.

How to interpret this correctly? I mean:

- does it allow POSIX compliant system to return nonsense, where `ST_RDONLY` is meaningfull?
- if statvfs structure member is meaningful for particular filesystem, is OS allowed to return nonsense (I understand some fields may have no meaning for synthetic filesystems like /proc)?

Is there any OS known to return incorrect `ST_RDONLY` or `ST_NOSUID` for filesystems used to store data/executables, while claiming POSIX compatibility of it's `statvfs()` implementation?

Comment: Typically, for flag type structure values, if you were interested in e.g. `ST_RDONLY`, you would test only that bit, via `(f & ST_RDONLY) == ST_RDONLY` or just `(f & ST_RDONLY)`, and not care about the values of other bits in the flag word. So a "nonsense" value isn't really interesting, as it may have additional bits used for something non-standard...

Comment: @twalberg, statvfs structure holds more fields, not just `ft_flag`. I understand how to take their values. I don't understand when exactly these values can be trusted.

Comment: @kestasx they can't be, at least not across POSIX. Linux handles `statvfs` gracefully, but both OS X and FreeBSD return garbage member data. On those platforms, `statfs` generally behaves better.

Comment: @woodruffw, thanks for response. I'm looking just now to FreeBSD (v9.1) and from what I see it seems there is not difference what `statvfs()` and `statfs()` return (where meaning of fields is the same). Tested ufs and zfs. If You have some example to confirm the oposite, con You post it please?

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX spec requires very little of `statvfs()`, aside from its existence.

In particular, it requires that `statvfs()` fill the specified `struct statvfs *` buffer with "information about the file system," but does **not** guarantee the meaning of that information. In other words it could be complete garbage and in fact is on many systems (including HFS+ on OS X).

That **includes** the `f_flag` member of `struct statvfs`, which *can* be masked to `ST_RDONLY` and/or `ST_NOSUID` but many not be on all filesystems (even when it should be).

If you need to reliably obtain filesystem information across multiple platforms, you may (ironically) have to resort to an unstandardized function like `statfs()`. On Linux, however, `statvfs()` behaves pretty well on most non-synthetic filesystems.

Comment: Thank You for an answer. Can Yo post data confirming these inconsistencies (especially regarding ST_RDONLY and ST_NOSUID)? Or sample to confirm `statvfs()` returns garbage, while `statfs()` shows correct info (for non-synthetic filesystem)? I'm aware of similar interpretation of the standart (FreeBSD manual, dated 2002), but I'm interested if this interpretation is valid (from formal point of view) and if it still holds in real world (it is 2014 now, there were changes both in standart and in OS implementations).

Comment: I no longer have a mac, but I remember testing `statvfs()` on it when I did. I never checked the `f_flag` member, but the other members would return garbage on HFS+ partitions. You might want to try it in a FreeBSD VM. POSIX is extremely forgiving with the `statvfs()` specification. I know for a fact that OS X's `statvfs()` is POSIX conformant, and FreeBSD's latest man page claims the same. The warning it gives is pretty useful (shortened): "As standardized, portable applications cannot depend on these functions returning any valid information at all."

Comment: I've already checked FreeBSD-9.1 (see comment below question). I've read it's manual page too, but I'm not sure it is correct and up-to-date interpretation of the standart, especially regarding `f_flag` values. I'm looking for formal/official interpretation, or verifiable examples.

Comment: Isn't the standard clear enough? It says that **none** of the members can be trusted to have reasonable values. The only things that are guaranteed are the presence of the `statvfs()` function and the presence of the `statvfs` struct. The meaning of `f_flag` therefore depends **solely** upon the operating system and **not** POSIX. If you need a concrete example of this, check out QNX's `statvfs()` [page](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fs%2Fstatvfs.html). It lists filesystems that can be read properly by the operating system.

Comment: Thank You for the link. Standart **wording is different** - I suspect it links return values to filesystem properties. And I think QNX manual You've linked confirms this - correct values are returned where relevant/known by OS). The same seems to be true for Solaris 11 manual.

Comment: That's what I was trying to impart. Sorry if I was ambiguous.